# 2-opt vrp problem Python for loop overwrite Memory Error

Tags: python, for-loop, out-of-memory

I want to make 2-opt vehicle routing problem.
so, I need to change route between vehicles.
Under Number of orders 500, work well
But Over number of orders 500, Memory error.

The result of route_list is structured as [[route of the first vehicle], [route of the second vehicle], ...]. I want to cut these routes into their closest neighbors and exchange their paths with each other.

Even if there are more than 500 routes, there are cases where the number of vehicles is low or the memory error is not encountered depending on the position of the depot.

```
def route_to_y_matrix(number_of_orders, matrix):
    binary_matrix = np.zeros((number_of_orders + 1, len(matrix)), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            number = matrix[i][j]
            vehicle = i
            binary_matrix[number][vehicle] = 1
    return binary_matrix

def route_to_x_matrix(number_of_orders, matrix):
    binary_matrix = np.zeros((number_of_orders + 1, number_of_orders + 1), dtype=np.uint8)
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])+1):
            if j == 0:
                start_node =0
            else:
                start_node = matrix[i][j-1]
            if j == len(matrix[i]):
                end_node = 0
            else:
                end_node = matrix[i][j]
            binary_matrix[start_node][end_node] = 1
    return binary_matrix

def cost(c_ij, x_ij, y_ik, y_ik_):

    f_1 = c_ij*x_ij
    f_2 = np.abs(y_ik[1:]-y_ik_)
    l_k = np.mat(c_ij*x_ij)@np.mat(y_ik)
    sum_f_1 = np.sum(f_1)
    sum_f_2 = np.sum(f_2)
    sum_l_k = np.sum(l_k, axis=0)
    std_f_3 = np.std(sum_l_k)

    return (1/3)*sum_f_1 + (1/3)*sum_f_2 + (1/3)*std_f_3


improved = False
           # if N == 0:
        for z in range(len(routes_list)-1):
           for y in range(len(routes_list[z])-2):
               try :
                   x_i = routes_list[z][y]
                   loc = neighborhood_location(nearest_neighbors[x_i], routes_list)
                   change_x = routes_list[z][:y] + routes_list[loc[0]][loc[1]+1:]
                   change_y = routes_list[loc[0]][:loc[1]] + routes_list[z][y+1:]
                   copy_list = copy.deepcopy(routes_list)
                   copy_list[z]=change_x
                   copy_list[loc[0]]=change_y
                   y_ik = route_to_y_matrix(end_of_xy, copy_list)
                   x_ij = route_to_x_matrix(end_of_xy, copy_list)
                   new_cost = cost(distance_matrix, x_ij, y_ik, y_ik_)
                   if new_cost < best_cost:
                       improved = True
                       print("new_cost : ", new_cost)
                       routes_list = copy_list
               except:
                   print("pass")
```

How can I fix my code?

Comment: Apparently you have some code, and some input data, which produce unsatisfactory output data. [Share them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with us, along with the _desired_ outputs.